# Converting text to UTF-8 within PHP script

Tags: php, html

I am exporting data to CSV from a dynamic html table.

However this causes some problems because sometimes the data has control characters etc.

I need all these stripped out or made 'friendly' if possible?

I have no idea how to do this so could anyone help?

Here is my script:

```
<textarea name="siteurl" rows="10" cols="50">
<?php //Check if the form has already been submitted and if this is the case, display the     submitted content. If not, display 'http://'.
echo (isset($_GET['siteurl']))?htmlspecialchars($_GET['siteurl']):"http://";?>
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id="nofloat"></div>
<table class="metadata" id="metatable_1">
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
function parseUrl($url){
    //Trim whitespace of the url to ensure proper checking.
    $url = trim($url);
    //Check if a protocol is specified at the beginning of the url. If it's not,    prepend 'http://'.
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
            $url = "http://" . $url;
    }
    //Check if '/' is present at the end of the url. If not, append '/'.
    if (substr($url, -1)!=="/"){
            $url .= "/";
    }
    //Return the processed url.
    return $url;
}
//If the form was submitted
if(isset($_GET['siteurl'])){
    //Put every new line as a new entry in the array
    $urls = explode("\n",trim($_GET["siteurl"]));
    //Iterate through urls
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
            //Parse the url to add 'http://' at the beginning or '/' at the end if not    already there, to avoid errors with the get_meta_tags function
            $url = parseUrl($url);
            //Get the meta data for each url
            $tags = get_meta_tags($url);
            //Check to see if the description tag was present and adjust output    accordingly
            $tags = NULL;
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
if($tags)
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>" .$tags['description']. "</td></tr>";
else 
echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>No Meta Description</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var exportTable1=new ExportHTMLTable('metatable_1');
    </script>
<div>
        <input type="button" onclick="exportTable1.exportToCSV()"   value="Export to CSV"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="exportTable1.exportToXML()"     value="Export to XML"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you try `utf8_encode()` function?

Comment: @Qmal I have looked at it, but how would I put this into my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like:

`echo "<tr><td>Description($url)</td><td>" . utf8_encode($tags['description']) . "</td></tr>";`

Please specify what text is it that is displaying wrong, is it `$tags['description']`?

Here are the manuals for function you probably need: [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if all you want is an UTF-8 encoded CSV, you could just use `utf8_encode()` on the data you're writing to the file.

Alternatively, if you want to omit control chars, you could check the lines for controle chars before writing them to the file using `ctype_cntrl()`... and then, using either a regular expression to get rid of them, or refuse to write the lines all together.